# Intents and google maps api v2

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, android-fragments

I know that my question is silly, but i'm a bit confused with Intents.From the code below i want to separate it in two classes ShowMap and LocationMap.How can i do this??The fist to contain only the map(FragmentActivity), from where i call the second class in which i want to find the user's current location and return the marker to the map(first activity).Thanks in advance!Here is the class which i want to separate:

```
public class LocationMap extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener{

private GoogleMap googleMap;
private LatLng latLng;
TextView tvLocation;
MarkerOptions markerOptions;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.location_maps);


    // Getting Google Play availability status        
       int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

    // Showing status
    if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

        int requestCode = 10;
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
        dialog.show();

    }else { // Google Play Services are available

        // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_main.xml
        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
        googleMap = fm.getMap();


      //setting zoomIn-zoomOut bar in the screen
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        //googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        // Getting the name of the best provider
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        // Getting Current Location
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        if(location!=null){
            onLocationChanged(location);
            new ReverseGeocodingTask(getBaseContext()).execute(latLng);

                      }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);
    }


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.location_maps, menu);

    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
            .getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
            .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu); 

}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Take appropriate action for each action item click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_search:

        return true;


    case R.id.menu_settings:
        // refresh
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}


   @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
       googleMap.clear();


    // Getting latitude of the current location
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();

    // Getting longitude of the current location
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();

    // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
     latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);



      // Showing the current location in Google Map
      googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

    // Zoom in the Google Map
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10));

    markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

    // Setting the position for the marker
     markerOptions.position(latLng);

   // Executing ReverseGeocodingTask to get Address
   new ReverseGeocodingTask(getBaseContext()).execute(latLng);



   }


@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      

    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),
    "Gps Disabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    }


@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}



private class ReverseGeocodingTask extends AsyncTask<LatLng, Void, String>{
    Context mContext;

    public ReverseGeocodingTask(Context context){
        super();
        mContext = context;
    }

    // Finding address using reverse geocoding
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(LatLng... params) {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(mContext);
        double latitude = params[0].latitude;
        double longitude = params[0].longitude;

        List<Address> addresses = null;
        String addressText="";

        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude,1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0 ){
            Address address = addresses.get(0);

            addressText = String.format("%s, %s, %s",
            address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address.getAddressLine(0) : "",
            address.getLocality(),
            address.getCountryName());
        }

        return addressText;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String addressText) {
        TextView tvLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_location);
        Log.v ("4",addressText );
        tvLocation.setText(addressText);


        // Setting the title for the marker.
        markerOptions.title(addressText);      


       googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);


    }
}
```

} }

Comment: What exactly is your question?  You can edit your submission to add more information.

Comment: If your goal is to show the user's current location on a map, there's no need for two activities.  Why do you want to get the current location in a different activity and then return to the map?

Comment: my pyrpose is when the user enters the application to show his current location or to give him the ability to search for an address on the map.

Comment: Taking look of two example on my github [here](https://github.com/jbj88817/GoogleMapExample-android) and [here](https://github.com/jbj88817/getLastLocationUsingGPS-android), combine them can reach your goal.